# Centre div in remaining line space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work out the best way using CSS to keep Block 2 centred in the remaining space that exists to the right of Block 1. This space could increase or decrease with the size of the browser window / orientation of device. Block1's position does not move.

I was hoping to be able to use a combination of float, margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto as way of keep Block2 centred, however, sadly my CSS is still in it's infancy.

Any guidance / help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#block1 {
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#009;
}

#block2 {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:10px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#999;
}

<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4agp0h6/

Thanks in advance[image: Div centre alignment in the remaining space after Block1]

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code?

Comment: can you create a demo of code using jsfiddle.net and share? That will be more helpful!

Comment: added code and link to jsfiddle. thanks for helping.

Comment: Did any solution worked for you??? If yes, please accept the one which  is correct so it can help others in future. And upvote other nearly correct answers to appreciate them!!!

Comment: Hi UID, thanks to everyone for their help. I'm currently going through all the replies testing each case for my purpose. Whilst all replies are very valid to my question, at present Christina's answer seems to be closest to my requirement. I'll confirm as soon as all is tested. Once again, many thanks to all that contributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want a fixed side bar and a fluid content area.

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fem4uf6c/1/

CSS:

```
body, html {padding:0;margin:0;}

#side {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
#box2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    background: purple;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="side"></div>
<div class="content">
    
    <p>This is the content box. Text inside here centers. Block items need margin: 0 auto; inline and inline-blocks will auto center.</p>
    
<div id="box2"></div>

    
</div>
```

Comment: Christina thank you for your help. This answer has translated it's way into my solution.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this would be to use nested `divs` rather than trying to position two within the same block element.

Here's the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4agp0h6/37/)

So, you create a wrapper (`#block1`) which is the size of the entire page so you can move stuff around inside. Position each subsequent piece of content within this area so you can set margins, position, etc.

**HTML**

```
<div id="block1">
    <div id="block2">
        <div id="content">
            <p>This is some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, with your CSS, set the positions relative to one another so you can use margins and percentage spacing to keep things fluid.

**CSS**

```
#block1 {
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    background:#555;
}

#block2 {
    position:relative;
    width:75%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#999;
}

#content {
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    top:45%;
}

#content p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for your reply. The example provided on jsfiddle doesn't demonstrate the div keeping centred when the window increases or decreases in size.

Comment: It is, but because the size of the paragraph block wasn't defined, it didn't appear so. [Here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/d4agp0h6/37/) with a more dramatic position set up.

Answer (score 1):

## **Option 1**

Here is one of the correct way of putting Block side by side... where one Block is on the Top Left... and the other Block is Top Center

### Working Demo 1 : **http://jsfiddle.net/wjtnddy5/**

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainBlock">
    <div id="block1">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#mainBlock {
     height:98%;
    width:98.9%;
    border:5px solid #000;
}
#block1 {
    width:10%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#block2 {
    width:89.2%;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:1px solid #ff0000;
    display:inline-block;
}
.box {
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#009;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Its using the "**`display:inline-block;`**" to put Blocks side by side which is better than using **`Float`** technique... let me know incase you need only Float!

## **Option 2**

Here is the Other technique using "**float: left**" incase you need this only...

For this I have just replaced "display:inline-block" with "float: left" for both Blocks.... rest is same..

### **Working Demo 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/h78poh52/**

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: Hi UID. Thank you for your help. The jsfiddle example provided on my screen is split over two lines. I'm trying to keep both blocks on the same line with the block2 being centred in the remaining horizontal space after block1 - albeit on the same level(line/flow position).

Comment: The Lines in Red color are coming because I gave red border for both blocks just to show you these blocks... I have removed those.. I have updated the Fiddle... Now is this what you are to achieve?  http://jsfiddle.net/d4agp0h6/36/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on a solution. I used [Brian Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278429/brian-bennett)'s fiddle as a base, since I agreed with how he laid out the markup and was going to do something similar myself.

[**Link to JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yr3tdw5/7/)

Where I differed is to add a container section:

```
<section id='container'>
    <div id="block1"></div>
    <div id="block2">
       <div id="content">
          <p>This is some text</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I also used percentages to determine widths instead of px values - with the exception of `#container`. Changing the width of the container should demonstrate that the relevant content is always centered.